# Masstransit one fault consumer for all fault message

Tags: masstransit

How to have one generic consumer that handle all Fault Messages ?

Do I need to register Fault Consumer for each of my fault messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not consume `Fault`?

```
public class WantAllFaultsGimmeThem : IConsumer<Fault>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault> context)
    {
        // whatever you want to do here
    }
}
```

The only issue is that the `Message` is not part of this interface and therefore it will not be even deserialised. so you will not have access to the message, only to the message id.

Comment: If I register WantAllFaultsGimmeThem for each of my ReceiveEndpoint, I receive duplicate Fault, now I register juste for one ReceiveEndpoint and that configure the other too..., The solution is good

Comment: If you did want to later get the actual fault message, you could use `consumeContext.TryGetMessage<Fault<T>>(out var faultContext)` and if it was present you'd get it back.

Comment: All Faults are being published to the bus, not to an endpoint. If you have multiple consumer of the same message type in multiple endpoints - they will all get it, just usual pub-sub.

Comment: But I want Fault only for my application, not for all Fault on the bus... I want log exception only after the end of retry process

Comment: You have enough details in the fault to determine where is it coming from. Plus, a custom middleware is probably better in case you just want logging.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I tried to get the message using `consumeContext.TryGetMessage<Fault<T>>(out var faultContext)`, but the faultContext value remains NULL. I am not able to get the message.