# MassTransit - subscribing to all fault events on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm aware of a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623670/masstransit-one-fault-consumer-for-all-fault-message) but don't have enough rep to comment and ask for clarification.

I've been trying to achieve a similar thing as the accepted answer suggests, with one service on *Azure Service Bus* capturing all `Fault` events, but can't see any events of type `Fault` being published.

This is how I'm subscribed:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
sbc =>
{
    var host = ConfigureServiceBus(serviceBusPath, sbc);
    sbc.SubscriptionEndpoint<Fault>(host, subscriptionName,
    ec => { ec.Consumer<FaultConsumerBase>(context); });
})
```

Where `FaultConsumerBase : IConsumer<Fault>`.
I can see my subscriber under `masstransit/fault/FaultEventSubscription`.

From the [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/exceptions.html), the examples are all of subscribers `Fault<T>`.
So,

1. Does MassTransit still publish all `Fault` events, or will it always be `Fault<T>`?
2. If yes, how does one subscribe to these? If no, what is the recommended pattern to catch all published Faults (just once) on the service bus?
   A service that is constantly updated with subscriptions to new events, for example, would be undesirable.

Comment: Have you tried? It doesn't work?

Comment: Azure Service Bus doesn't have the support for polymorphic message consumers like RabbitMQ does, so that's why it doesn't work on ASB.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @ChrisPatterson. What would be the next best alternative to capture this? I'm thinking of a generic [consume observer](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/observers.html) with a `ConsumeFault` implementation that I enforce being attached to all subscribers.

Comment: The IConsumeObserver implementation would work, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @ChrisPatterson in comment to my quesiton, this is does not work on ASB due to the fact that ASB does not support polymorphic messaging.